# Difficulty Opening Text File

Tags: swift, text, nstextview

I'm trying to incorporate a file browser that allows the user to select a text file, and have the contents of the file displayed in a NSTextView. I have the file browser working and the text box working but I can't seem to open the file and generate at least one or preferably a series of strings from it (1 per line).

```
let FileWindow : NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    FileWindow.prompt = "Open File"
    FileWindow.title = "Select a File"
    FileWindow.allowedFileTypes = ["txt"]
    FileWindow.canChooseDirectories = false
    FileWindow.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    FileWindow.runModal()
    var selectedfile = FileWindow.URL
    var output = selectedfile?.absoluteString
    var index: String.Index = advance(output!.startIndex, 7)
    FileLabel.stringValue = output!.substringFromIndex(index)

if (selectedfile != nil) {
var data: NSData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(output!.substringFromIndex(index))!
        var txt: NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        self.FileDisplayView.textStorage?.mutableString.appendString(txt)
        self.FileDisplayView.needsDisplay = true
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated: **Xcode 7.1 • Swift 2.1**

You should use String(contentsOfFile:) or String(contentsOfURL:)

Create this class to handle opening text files:

```
public class File {

    class func open(path: String, encoding: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> String? {
        guard  NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) else { return nil }
        do {
            return try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: encoding)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
    class func save(path: String, fileContent: String, encoding: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> Bool {
        do {
            try fileContent.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: encoding)
            return true
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }
}

class Url {
    class func read(urL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> String? {
        do {
            return try String(contentsOfURL: urL, encoding: encoding)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
    class func write(urL: NSURL, fileContent: String, encoding: NSStringEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding) -> Bool {
        do {
            try fileContent.writeToURL(urL, atomically: true, encoding: encoding)
            return true
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

usage would be like this:

```
if let loadedString = File.open("\(NSHomeDirectory())/Desktop/file.txt") {
    println(loadedString)
} else {
    println("error reading file")
}
```

or to open your URL:

```
if let loadedString = Url.read(yourUrl) {
    println(loadedString)
} else {
    println("error reading file")
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use NSString. Just use String instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the information! I only needed to read the file for now so I just implemented that one but it's working great now. Thanks so much!